# Can GCC use read-modify-write instructions to update volatile variables?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, x86, port

Suppose you have C code for x86 systems code like this:

```
volatile uint32_t *reg = (volatile uint32_t *)0xCAFEBABE;
// ...
reg[0x10] |= 1;
```

Is GCC free to generate a read-modify-write instruction here? If so, will encapsulating the read and write to the volatile variable in functions make sure that GCC does not combine the accesses into a single RMW instruction?

I know that the C spec is intentionally vague about this.

Comment: why not trying yourself with some magical flag that generates the assembly? (I dont have gcc and never worked with it so I dont know the flags too well)

Comment: Encapsulating R/W into different functions most probably will avoid the problem only by a lucky coincidence, as the compiler is free to inline and then optimize. Btw, what platform are you developing for?

Answer (score 5):

The C standard does not specify what instruction is to be used. For a simple update like this `gcc` is most liklely to generate a single RMW instruction the style of

```
orl (%rdx), $1
```

The `volatile` keyword has nothing to do with it though. any combination of `load, modify, store` would have been valid too. The `volatile` keyword only tells the compiler to reload the value from memory on every use instead of using register caching optimisations.

If you want an atomic update then you need atomics, gcc provides for this `_sync_fetch_and_or(type *, type)`

Comment: On x86 GCC generally avoids RMW instructions for `volatile`, doing a separate `mov` load and `mov` store.  https://godbolt.org/z/1K4hsbs5d  shows *clang* will use a memory-destination `or`, though.  (Which does happen to be atomic wrt. interrupts on a single core, but not atomic wrt. to other cores.  And not something you can count on ever.)  Also, the `__sync` builtins were deprecated even before 2014; new code should `__atomic` builtins: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html